# Vmware cannot create snapshot

Tags: backup, vmware, snapshot

I use Veeam to backup our servers, it has been running smoothly for years. Veeam creates a snapshot of the VM and than backs up this snapshot. After completion the backup job deletes the snapshot. Due to an aborted backup job, the some of the snapshot files were not deleted. I tried to consolidate the snapshot, that runs through but it doesn't delete the old delta.vmdk files. I tried to create a snapshot, but that fails with msg.snapshot.error-NOTFOUND
When I connect to the ESXi I can see the delta files dated from June 8th, I think that might be the problem why I cannot create a snapshot:
[ls -l of the vm files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A8gnL.jpg)

I ran throught different articles in the knowledge base of Vmware but I couldn't find an answer.

Can anybody help me with this issue?

Thanks

Kind regards

Comment: Are you able to clone the virtual machine?

Comment: Yes I could clone the machine, but this is a production server with 300GB of disk space, it would take an eternity to copy forth and back.

Comment: There is a reason for that question.  Does this virtual machine currently have any snapshots currently?

Comment: No it has no snapshots

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I think I solved the problem. I recreated the vmdk files as a copy of the main vmdk file.

This is explained here:

[Recreating a missing virtual disk (VMDK) descriptor file for delta disks (1026353)](http://Recreating%20a%20missing%20virtual%20disk%20(VMDK)%20descriptor%20file%20for%20delta%20disks%20(1026353)/)

What is important is that the CID, parentCID and parentFileNameHint match.

How to change the CID and parentCID is explained here:

[The parent virtual disk has been modified since the child was created" error (1007969)](https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/1007969?other.KM_Utility.getArticleMetadata=2&CoveoV2.ContentHandler.getLoader=1&other.KM_Utility.getUser=1&other.KM_Utility.getAllTranslatedLanguages=2&other.KM_Utility.getContentdocument=1&ui-comm-runtime-components-aura-components-siteforce-qb.Quarterback.validateRoute=1&other.KM_Utility.getViewCount=1&r=1&other.KM_Utility.getKnowDetails=1&ui-communities-components-aura-components-forceCommunity-seoAssistant.SeoAssistant.getSeoData=1&CoveoV2.EndpointHandler.getEndpoint=1&other.KM_Utility.getUrl=1&other.KM_Utility.getPRNumberLinks=1&other.KM_Utility.getCaseLike=1)

After these steps I could create a snapshot. And you were right I can delete those
old delta files, but I will first consolidate.